# Kernel Base Test: Create node content types and taxonomy vocabularies via configuration?

Tags: 8, testing

Does anybody know, how the mentioned entity types can be setup via configuration Yaml files? Right now I am setting up my entity types for a Kernel Base Test like the following:

```
Vocabulary::create([
  'name' => 'Kreise',
  'vid' => 'districts',
])->save();

$stringFields = [
  'field_district_number',
];
$this->saveFields($stringFields, 'string', 'districts', 'taxonomy_term');

$booleanFields = [
  'field_searchable'
];
$this->saveFields($booleanFields, 'boolean', 'districts', 'taxonomy_term');
```

Is it possible to quickly load the entity type configuration by an existing site configuration to save time? Because I already have configured entity types in my site configuration. It seems like an not necessary additional step, to code the entity configuration for my test.

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for using the configuration. 
So for example, if you want to load Tags Vocabulary you will do:

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('taxonomy.vocabulary.tags');
$description = $config->get('description');
```

$description contains the description of the vocabulary. In this way, you can load what you want from the yml file.

Comment: Loading the description is not loading the entity type configuration tho. I would image you need to load the configuration of the entity after exporting the config?